# Equivalent of console input in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal

I am new to node.js, and was wondering if there's any kind of way/built-in methods or modules that I can use to get the terminal input in node.js to work similarly as browser consoles. For instance, the chrome console runs whatever I put into the console (i.e. typing in `myFunc()` will run the function), or remembers variabls (it will remember any function/variable declaration you type into the console).

The closest I have come to making it is this:

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})
readline.on('line', (input) => {
    try {
        console.log(eval(input));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    };
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the “agrv” object?

Comment: @evolutionxbox doesn't agrv only allow you to pass an argument in the beginning? and not if the program has already started

Comment: You are correct. I had misunderstood what you were asking. Have you tried using the command `node` without any arguments?

Comment: You could try using the REPL module if you need some more control https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html